# How to calculate minimum speed a ball needs to be rolling to move up when hitting a wall?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction, moment-of-inertia

> A ball of mass $m$ is rolling on the floor without sliding towards a vertical wall. Friction coefficient between the ball and the wall is $u$ and standard gravity is $g$. Ball and the wall are perfectly elastic with an infinite elasticity coefficient and the collision is very short.
>
> What is the minimal velocity of the ball necessary for the ball to "jump" as a result of the collision?

My way of thinking:
Because the collision lasts is "very short" the force acting perpendicular to the surface of the wall on the ball is very large. Thus so is the friction. Thus the inertia is transformed into vertical motion. This would mean no matter the speed the ball would move up. This doesn't seem to be a correct answer though.

How to correctly calculate the velocity necessary given only the data in the text? Why is my approach incorrect?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: I know this is not a homework help site and I read the meta-post. This question seemed similar to the "Good" examples because I went to know the approach necessary, not the exact answer.

Comment: So what ideas have you had as to how to solve this problem?

Comment: Because the collision lasts is "very short" the force acting perpendicular to the surface of the wall on the ball is very large. Thus so is the friction. Thus the inertia is transformed into vertical motion. This would mean no matter the speed the ball would move up. This doesn't seem to be a correct answer though.

Comment: You should go beyond wanting to know the approach necessary and ask about a specific concept that is keeping you from figuring it out. Right now, your question doesn't actually ask _anything_.

Comment: @DavidZ is it OK now? I am pretty new here, it seems to adhere to all the rules. Or should I ask "How to calculate the maximum vertical force acting on the ball, that compared to $mg$ will give the answer"?

Comment: It's probably a decent rule of thumb that asking "how to calculate [anything]" will not help you much. So no, it's not OK now (although you do at least have an actual question in there, which is better than before). I'd suggest that you try applying some formulas to this problem. Take some time to do some quantitative work on it. I think that will lead you in the direction of formulating a better question.

Comment: I have no idea how to even start the calculations, thus I cannot apply any formulas. If I knew which formulas to use I would have solved the task. Could you please edit this question to be acceptable this one time to show me the proper way of asking them? I am trying to learn, just nothing seems to work.

Comment: @JohnRennie what do I have to do to get this unlocked? It seems to be getting upvoted.

Comment: You say that your approach does not give a correct answer. What answer are you expecting to get?